# Ubuntu 15.10 dual booting with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I have Windows 10 installed on my laptop and I installed Ubuntu onto a partition.

When I boot, it automatically boots into Ubuntu 15.10, I chose to mount the C: drive to /win/ how do I boot into Windows?

Comment: Try opening the terminal (CTRL + ALT + T) and entering `sudo update-grub` to see what happens. It will ask for a password, type it in - nothing changes on the screen and this is normal. Follow any prompts, should be none, and reboot.

Comment: Thanks @KGIII, I haven't tested that out yet but this seems promising, read the last line of the log `lmgn@lmgn-Alienware-14:~$ sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for lmgn: 
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 10 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
`

Comment: I put it into a formal answer with the correct steps. If this is the correct answer and it worked for you, please make sure to accept the answer so as to remove it from the answer queue and to ensure others are more easily able to find the answer while searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happened is `GRUB` (GRand Unifying Bootloader) had, for one reason or another, not included the Windows install pointers (so to speak). So it wasn't showing Windows as an option during the boot process.

The easiest way to fix this is to use the terminal. To open the terminal press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

When the terminal has opened enter the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on your keyboard. At this point you will be asked for your password. Type your password. Note, while typing your password nothing on the screen will change. You will see no asterisks, the cursor will not move. This is normal behavior. Type your password and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> again.

Follow any on-screen prompts (there should be none) and then reboot your system to ensure the changes have taken effect.

Answer (score 0):

If grub does not detect it, it might have something to do with UEFI. Did you install Ubuntu with UEFI support?

You could try to install ubuntu with UEFI like this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI it should it show up it grub.

If all fails, you can always press some F-key (or from bios) to boot into Windows. Depending on your laptop. It could be F8 or F12 or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I always have to run this tool after I dual boot to get the boot menu to see both OS's.

http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/