# Windows 10/ Xubuntu 15.10 Dual Boot // error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'

Tags: boot, dual-boot, xubuntu, windows-10

I've been experiencing some problems trying to set up a Dual-Boot with Windows 10 and Xubuntu 15.10. I had been using dual-boot Windows 7/ Xubuntu 15.04 and it worked perfectly until i decided to upgrade Xubuntu 15.04 to 15.10. Upon coming up with the error i decided to install Windows 10. I first did the upgrade then a clean install from USB. I installed keeping no files. It kept the partition arrangement though.

Partitions were 100MB system + 150 GB Windows + 520 GB extended + 25 Recovery, on this order (aprox values)

I intalled Xubuntu 15.10 and the problem with UEFI/Legacy boot appeared. It entered Xubuntu straight away or Windows straight away.
[Ubuntu 15.10 dual booting with Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689483/ubuntu-15-10-dual-booting-with-windows-10) 
GRUB was not coming on and I was able to get it back with a Boot Repair. Windows 10 was now available.

Xubuntu was installed on a new partition created on the 500GB extended, with 40 Gb for / and 8 for swap.

I used this setup for a whole day and a half using only Xubuntu. Then I shut down the laptop and upon powering it on the next day it gave me the error:

"error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'"

I entered GRUB several times to try and recover the boot but nothing was effective. I managed somehow to enter Xubuntu with many errors appearing but upon shutting it down the error kept appearing. I decided to eliminate Xubuntu and try a fresh install but changing partitions. I recovered MBR from Windows command prompt and entered Windows to eliminate all partitions except the partition with windows and the system one.

Partitions were now:

100MB system + 150 GB Windows + 8GB NTFS + 40 GB NTFS + 500 Extended (aprox values)

The 8 GB and 40 GB were reserved for Xubuntu. It installed and formatted both partitions for swap and ext4 mounting on /.

The 500 GB was reserved for media. I never keep anything where I have my OS.

All ok but the fact that it entered straight to Xubuntu again. GRUB disappeared but it would appear by holding down shift key. I installed the updates and it managed the issue and I now had GRUB with Windows option and no problem whatsoever.

Only that again, the same error after a day and a half of use

error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'

has come about.

What should I do here? Is it a problem with partitions? I read that I should try to install Linux the closest possible to the start of the disk. Is the 100 MB system a problem here? is it Windows 10? or my laptop's BIOS from 2010? Should I update the BIOS? I'm fairly new to Linux and I need to keep a dual-boot which seems to be my major problem now.

I use a Samsung RC530, Intel (R) Core (TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.2Ghz
8GB DDR 3 SDRAM
x64 
NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M

thank you

Comment: With BIOS and MBR(msdos) partitioning you can only have 4 primary partitions. You are listing 5?? Post this: `sudo parted -l` Partitions are fine, and if anything all your Linux partitions can or should be in the extended as logical. Only some very old systems or perhaps USB full installs may need a / or /boot within the first part of drive.